# type mapping with transport client doesnt work in spring application

Tags: elasticsearch, spring-data-elasticsearch

I've got the following configuration inside spring application:

```
@Configuration
public class config {

    @Bean
    public TransportClient elasticsearchSecuredClient() throws Exception {
        // Based on https://github.com/elastic/found-shield-example/blob/master/src/main/java/org/elasticsearch/cloud/transport/example/TransportExample.java
        Settings settings = Settings.builder().build();

        XContentBuilder xContentBuilder = XContentFactory.jsonBuilder().
                startObject().
                startObject("mappings").
                    startObject("restaurant").
                        startObject("properties").
                            startObject("amount").field("type", "long").endObject().

                        endObject().
                        field("dynamic", "strict").
                    endObject().
                endObject().
                endObject();

        TransportClient localhost = new PreBuiltTransportClient(settings)
                .addTransportAddress(new InetSocketTransportAddress(new InetSocketAddress("localhost", 9300)));
        localhost.admin().indices().prepareCreate("expenses").addMapping("restaurant",xContentBuilder).get();
        return localhost;
    }
}
```

This is my entity :

```
@Data
@Document(indexName = "expenses",type = "restaurant")
public class ResturantExpenseEntity {

    //@Id
    //private String id;

    @Id
    private Long amount;


}
```

and this is the **stacktrace** of the error :

> org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException:
>   Error creating bean with name 'hello': Unsatisfied dependency
>   expressed through field 'repo'; nested exception is
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error
>   creating bean with name 'resturantExpensesRepo': Cannot resolve
>   reference to bean 'elasticsearchTemplate' while setting bean property
>   'elasticsearchOperations'; nested exception is
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException:
>   Error creating bean with name 'elasticsearchTemplate' defined in class
>   path resource
>   [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/data/elasticsearch/ElasticsearchDataAutoConfiguration.class]:
>   Unsatisfied dependency expressed through method
>   'elasticsearchTemplate' parameter 0; nested exception is
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error
>   creating bean with name 'elasticsearchSecuredClient' defined in class
>   path resource [hello/config.class]: Bean instantiation via factory
>   method failed; nested exception is
>   org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to
>   instantiate [org.elasticsearch.client.transport.TransportClient]:
>   Factory method 'elasticsearchSecuredClient' threw exception; nested
>   exception is MapperParsingException[Failed to parse mapping
>   [restaurant]: Root mapping definition has unsupported parameters: 
>   [mappings : {restaurant={dynamic=strict,
>   properties={amount={type=long}}}}]]; nested:
>   MapperParsingException[Root mapping definition has unsupported
>   parameters:  [mappings : {restaurant={dynamic=strict,
>   properties={amount={type=long}}}}]];  at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:581)
>   ~[spring-beans-5.0.1.RELEASE.jar:5.0.1.RELEASE]   at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InjectionMetadata.inject(InjectionMetadata.java:91)
>   ~[spring-beans-5.0.1.RELEASE.jar:5.0.1.RELEASE]   at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessPropertyValues(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:367)
>   ~[spring-beans-5.0.1.RELEASE.jar:5.0.1.RELEASE]   at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1340)
>   ~[spring-beans-5.0.1.RELEASE.jar:5.0.1.RELEASE]   at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:582)
>   ~[spring-beans-5.0.1.RELEASE.jar:5.0.1.RELEASE]   at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:502)
>   ~[spring-beans-5.0.1.RELEASE.jar:5.0.1.RELEASE]   at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:312)
>   ~[spring-beans-5.0.1.RELEASE.jar:5.0.1.RELEASE]   at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:228)
>   ~[spring-beans-5.0.1.RELEASE.jar:5.0.1.RELEASE]   at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:310)
>   ~[spring-beans-5.0.1.RELEASE.jar:5.0.1.RELEASE]   at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:200)
>   ~[spring-beans-5.0.1.RELEASE.jar:5.0.1.RELEASE]   at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:756)
>   ~[spring-beans-5.0.1.RELEASE.jar:5.0.1.RELEASE]   at
>   org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:868)
>   ~[spring-context-5.0.1.RELEASE.jar:5.0.1.RELEASE]     at
>   org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:549)
>   ~[spring-context-5.0.1.RELEASE.jar:5.0.1.RELEASE]

or in short, the error states that :
**Root mapping definition has unsupported parameters:  [mappings : {restaurant={dynamic=strict, properties={amount={type=long}}}}]];**

what am i doing wrong ?
I tried also with @Mapping annotation and giving a path for a json file with the same mapping, and i get the same result !

Please help :)
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

after trying everything , I found that the problem is putting everything under "mapping" object .

it should be without it , hence like this :

```
XContentBuilder xContentBuilder = XContentFactory.jsonBuilder().
                    startObject().
                        startObject("restaurant").
                            startObject("properties").
                                startObject("amount").field("type", "long").endObject().
                                startObject("id").field("type", "long").endObject().
                                startObject("name").field("type", "keyword").endObject().
                            endObject().
                            field("dynamic", "strict").
                        endObject().
                    endObject();
```